# `gradle.taskGraph.useFilter` not executing

Tags: gradle

I have the following in `build.gradle`:

```
def shouldExecute = { taskName ->
    def propertyName = "${taskName}.dryrun"

    !project.hasProperty(propertyName) || project[propertyName] != 'true'
}

gradle.taskGraph.useFilter({ task ->
    println("*********************** ${task.name}: ${shouldExecute(task.name)}")
    shouldExecute(task.name)
} as Spec)
```

But when I run `gradlew -Ptest.dryrun=true clean build`, I don't see the output of `println` and the `test` task is still executed. Why isn't the `useFilter` working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine for me. Only thing I added to the script above was `task test`. Then I ran `gradle test`, with and without `-Ptest.dryrun=true`. Both times I got the expected output and behavior. I can't think of a good reason why it wouldn't work for you. I recommend to start small (I'm sure it will work in that case) and gradually add back stuff until it stops working. Hopefully this will lead you to the cause of the problem.

Comment: It turns out the culprit is that I was using `-x someTask` on the command line and, if `-x` is used, `gradle.taskGraph.useFilter` doesn't get executed.